# Windows 8.1 (also phone) c#/xaml elements not visible on this scrollviewer, why?

Tags: c#, xaml, scroll, viewer

I'm having a problem with this code:

```
       <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="1999" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="filter1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#D8181818" Height="640" Width="400">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="FadeStoryboardbefore">
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="filter1"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"  Duration="0:0:0.4"
                             >
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="FadeStoryboardafter">
                <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="filter1"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"  Duration="0:0:0.4"
                             >
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ScrollViewer Canvas.ZIndex="2000" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="scroll_filter" Height="641" Width="400">
            <Grid Height="Auto" Canvas.ZIndex="2001" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  x:Name="bottoni_filtro" >
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
```

The problem is that when I add elements with filter1.childrens.add in `c#`, it works. With the second grid, bottoni_filtro.childrends.add doesn't work. When I start the app, it doesn't show elements on bottoni_filtro..

How can I fix that??

P.S. properties like width are set through code (c#)

Comment: Remove the zindex properties on both scrollviewer and grid, and put a fixed heigth on the grid for testing purposes. A grid without content will collapse (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: well, zindex cannot create this type of problem, also changing the height i think will not fix the problem becouse i have a grid>scrollv>grid with the same proprieties

Comment: P.S. in this grid i add elements of zindex 2001 and 2002